# How to use symbol to call active record search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Firstly, please excuse the poor title. I know what I want to solve, but I don't think I have the correct language to adequately describe the problem.

I have a database where each teaching course can belong to either a "Textbook" or "Targeted" style of teaching. At the moment, I save this information (Textbook or Targeted), dependent on the user choice, in a cookie.

I extract this information and, depending on the value, I want to search for records either relating to the textbook or targeted id.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
case coursetype
  when "textbook"
    activecourses = Course.find(topicid).textbook_children.where(active: true).order(:id)
    @lessons = Video.joins(:textbook_parent).where('courses.id' => activecourses.pluck(:id)).order(:id)
  else
    activecourses = Course.find(topicid).targeted_children.where(active: true).order(:id)
    @lessons = Video.joins(:targeted_parent).where('courses.id' => activecourses.pluck(:id)).order(:id)
 end
```

Which isn't very DRY.

I basically wish to write:

```
activecourses = Course.find(topicid).targeted_children.where(active: true).order(:id)
```

Where the **targeted_children** or **textbook_children** is some form of text string which becomes a symbol (if that's correct) but have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm sorry if I'm still not making it clear.

PS. I've self-taught myself a lot of ruby and rails. I'm sure the code could be written in a much nicer way ... I'd kill to work with someone who could help me improve ... but ... please don't judge!!

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere where you reference a symbol or a string you can replace with a variable that contains a symbol or string.

```
parent_type = (coursetype == 'textbook' ? :textbook_parent : :targeted_parent)
activecourses = Course.find(topicid).textbook_children.where(active: true).order(:id)
@lessons = Video.joins(parent_type).where('courses.id' => activecourses.pluck(:id)).order(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I debated leaving out the line of code with @lessons as I am already using `.to_sym`. But you have cleared something up for me there!! My problem is I want to replace the `.textbook_children` in the `activecourses` line with dynamically created text. Sorry for the confusion!!

Comment: So instead of `Course.find(topicid).textbook_children.where...` you can do `method = :textbook_children` and then `Course.find(topicid).send(method).where...`